# How to share computer's internet connection among network users

Tags: windows, networking, bluetooth, internet-sharing

I wanted to connect to internet from my mobile through laptop wireless-broadband internet connection..

For that I have gone to Network Places, there i have done appropriate settings for "Wireless Network Connection" and "Bluetooth Personal Area Network Connection",, but that Bluetooth connection is still not showing connected..

I have checked the option for "Allow other network users to connect through this computers Internet connection", but still my Bluetooth Connection is still showing not connected..

Please help me out,, as to how can i achieve the same,, as i am having Broadband internet connection, which comes wirelessly to my laptop through a router/modem..

Answer (score 0):

Very few mobile devices are able to connect to an internet connection over bluetooth.  What is your mobile device?